# Error: MSB4018: Method not found: Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlCmdFileVerifier..ctor

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I'm getting this error in Visual Studio 2017 15.5.2 when I compile my SSDT projects. But if I compile from the command line, it works as expected.

`` C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(559,5): Error:  MSB4018: The "SqlBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlCmdFileVerifier..ctor(Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSqlParser, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.String,System.String>, Boolean)'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.ExecutePrePostScriptsValidationStep()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.ExecuteStep(Func`1 step)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() ``

I've already tried a "Repair" on Visual Studio and manually reinstall SSDT.

Any other suggestions?

---

More info:

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 
Version 15.5.2
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.5.2+27130.2010
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02046

Installed Version: Enterprise

Visual Basic 2017   00369-90250-45713-AA233
Microsoft Visual Basic 2017

Visual C# 2017   00369-90250-45713-AA233
Microsoft Visual C# 2017

Visual C++ 2017   00369-90250-45713-AA233
Microsoft Visual C++ 2017

Visual F# 4.1   00369-90250-45713-AA233
Microsoft Visual F# 4.1

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   8.10.01106.1
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.0.31125.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017

ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   1.0
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017   5.2.51007.0
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   15.0.31106.0
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

CodeMaid   10.4.53
CodeMaid is an open source Visual Studio extension to cleanup and simplify our C#, C++, F#, VB, PHP, PowerShell, R, JSON, XAML, XML, ASP, HTML, CSS, LESS, SCSS, JavaScript and TypeScript coding.

CodeRush for Roslyn   17.2.4.0
DevExpress CodeRush for Roslyn package.

CodeRush for Roslyn Tool Windows   17.2.4.0
DevExpress CodeRush for Roslyn Tool Windows package.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

GhostDoc   5.8.17335.0
Generate XML Comments from your code, maintain clean and up-to-date documentation, produce help documentation in multiple formats, use intelligent source code Spell Checker in Visual Studio.

JavaScript Language Service   2.0
JavaScript Language Service

JavaScript Project System   2.0
JavaScript Project System

Markdown Editor   1.11.214
A full featured Markdown editor with live preview and syntax highlighting. Supports GitHub flavored Markdown.

Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 - v2.9.51120.3

Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.3
Simplifying the configuration of continuous build integration and continuous build delivery from within the Visual Studio IDE.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards   1.0
Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1
Develop, run, validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5 your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL + F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.

Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package

NuGet Package Manager   4.5.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

Redgate SQL Prompt   1.0
Write, format, and refactor SQL effortlessly

Snapshot Debugging Extension   1.0
Snapshot Debugging Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

**SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.61710.120
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools**

TypeScript Tools   15.5.11025.1
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after updating to 15.5.2 today. Upon some searching, I found this chain in a Redgate forum:
https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/82371/builds-now-fail-after-installing-sql-toolbelt

I had recently upgraded from an older version of SQL Prompt, too. When I downloaded and installed SQL Prompt v9.0.4.3408 as noted in the accepted answer, that fixed my issue.

Direct download link to SQL Prompt v9.0.4.3408 (from forum post above) is here: ftp://support.red-gate.com/patches/SQLPrompt/20Dec2017/SQLPrompt_9.0.4.3408.exe

Hope it is as simple for you.